# How to avoid the characters coverting when using GetBlockBlobReference()?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

When I use the method `GetBlockBlobReference()` of cloud block blob of Microsoft Azure, I find that it converts some characters like # to %23.That's not what I want. How can I avoid this?
the code segment just like follow:

```
string pvtFileName = "pvt/" + fileName.Replace(StlFilePostfix, PvtFilePostfix);//the name contains #
            BlobRequestOptions bl = new BlobRequestOptions();
            bl.RetryPolicy = new LinearRetry(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50), 6);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var blobContainerPVT = blobClient.GetContainerReference(smodContainer.ToLower());
            blobContainerPVT.CreateIfNotExists();
            try
            {
                CloudBlockBlob pvtBlob = blobContainerPVT.GetBlockBlobReference(pvtFileName);
                using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileFullPath.Replace(StlFilePostfix, PvtFilePostfix)))
                {
                    pvtBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream, null, bl);
                }} catch (Exception e)
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation(e.Message);
            }
```

No matter I use  HttpUtility.UrlEncode()to format the filename or not, the method will convert the # to %23

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. Since `#` is a reserved URL character, it needs to be properly escaped.

Comment: I upload a file to the Blob container, all follow the instruction of Microsoft Azure.

Comment: Where do you see the escaped character (`%23` instead of `#`)?

Comment: CloudBlockBlob pvtBlob = blobContainerPVT.GetBlockBlobReference(pvtFileName); I debug and step to this code, it returns the blob uri with %23 instead of #

Comment: The character “#” is unsafe and should always be encoded because it  delimit a URL from a fragment/anchor identifier that might follow it.

Comment: As @JoeyCai mentioned, in the blob URL `#` will be escaped and will be replaced with `%23`. However if you check the blob name, you should see `#` intact.

Answer (score 3):

A blob name must conforming to the following naming rules:

> A blob name can contain any combination of characters.
>
> A blob name must be at least one character long and cannot be more than 1,024 characters long.
>
> Blob names are case-sensitive.
>
> **Reserved URL characters must be properly escaped.**
>
> The number of path segments comprising the blob name cannot exceed 254. A path segment is the string between consecutive delimiter characters (e.g., the forward slash '/') that corresponds to the name of a virtual directory.

[image]

URIs that differ only by whether a [reserved character is percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) or appears literally are normally considered not equivalent (denoting the same resource) unless it can be determined that the reserved characters in question have no reserved purpose.

Here is  [A Complete Guide to URL Escape Characters](https://www.werockyourweb.com/url-escape-characters/).

Comment: So, here, How can I get the URI without the escape character? Because the filename is named by the customers, but when they download the files from the Blob again, the names changed.

Comment: The name is pointed to blob.name or blob.uri? If you only want to show blob uri with no escaped, you could use container.uri+blob.name to splice.